# addSubview animation works only after second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to make my label appear with animation:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (isShowingRectangleLabel == NO) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:rectangleLabel duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:rectangleLabel]; }
                    completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"action");
        isShowingRectangleLabel = YES;
    } else {
        [UIView transitionWithView:rectangleLabel duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                    animations:^ { [rectangleLabel removeFromSuperview]; }
                    completion:nil];
        isShowingRectangleLabel = NO;
    }

}
```

But this animation works only after second adding to subview. How can I fix it?

**EDIT** To clarify, `addSubview` works but without animation.

Comment: Just to be sure: have you verified that *isShowingRectangleLabel* is set to NO when you try the first time?

Comment: yes, in `viewDidLoad` I set it to `NO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (isShowingRectangleLabel == NO) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:rectangleLabel]; }
                    completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"action");
        isShowingRectangleLabel = YES;
    } else {
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                    animations:^ { [rectangleLabel removeFromSuperview]; }
                    completion:nil];
        isShowingRectangleLabel = NO;
    }

}
```